# UserControl - Run sub after control loaded

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a main form that loads a user control. Within that user control, when the user selects a button, I load another usercontrol in a panel (which is a control on the first user control (i.e. Form loads "Menu" usercontrol, User click on menu item and it loads the "Item" usercontrol, passing a variable)

To load the "item" usercontrol I use:

```
  Dim ctrl As New newSubMenuItem
  ctrl.theRecordID= theRecordID
  ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  PanelControl1.Controls.Add(ctrl)
```

Once my control loads, it then runs a load data function that takes 1 seconds to load.For the user it seems to "lag" a little bit and shows the control in the small size (for about 1-2 seconds) and then resizes and loads.

Using a form, I could use the "Shown" event to move my load data function, but not sure how to achieve this within a UserControl?

Comment: Add the sub as public and call it.  You are not limited to events but can add methods to them - which is somewhat the point of them.

Comment: I normally also set the Form Or Controls SuspendLayout property to false and true around functionality like this. That way the you should not see any changes till it is done. If the data loading routine is a background thing, you should have it raise and event when it is done.

Comment: AS for how to load it, that depends on if it needs information to load with. e.g. a lookup parameter or whatever. Generally you need to add a Method (Sub or Function) to the UserControl. Or you can augment the NEW function, possibly with parameters, if it's safe  to load on creation.